# infeasible solution in Python, pulp using COIN-OR

Tags: python, pulp, coin-or-cbc

I am trying to solve a Linear Programing problem using COIN-OR in python.
I have done all the work but there seems to be an error which I am not able to identify.
Many a times the solution comes out to be either infeasible or incorrect according the contraints that I am trying to force.
The values, the binary variable are also incorrect i.e. ~0.1^10 or ~ 0.999.....

Kindly help me to locate the error or try to guide to resolve the issue.

I am attaching

- zip file(code + input data file from excel)
- word doc. for the mathematical formulation

Model1 main class takes the input and create a new output file and then PanelTwo class methods build the Distance matrix and the Njg matrix.

There seems to be error in the constructor method of the Model1 class which builds theLP and solves the LP

[Here is the zip file](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/files/929931/schoolConsolidation_troubleshhoot.zip)

the code for the declaring the variables and constraints are:

M = 100000 * prob.schoolNum

```
    sModel = []
    for i in range(prob.schoolNum):
        sModel.append(i)
    gModel = []
    for i in xrange(prob.gradeNum):
        gModel.append(i)
    Beta = []

    for i in xrange(prob.schoolNum):
        temp = 0
        for j in xrange(prob.gradeNum):
            temp = temp + prob.Njg[i][j]
        if temp < prob.Nmax:
            Beta.append(0)
        else:
            Beta.append(1)


    # x = students of grade g transfer from school i to j
    x = LpVariable.matrix("x_igj_", (sModel, gModel, sModel), 0, 1, LpBinary)
    y = LpVariable.matrix("status of school", (sModel), 0, 1, LpBinary)
    # o = resulting students in grade in school
    o = LpVariable.matrix("o", (sModel, gModel), 0, None, LpInteger)

    # oHelper  = summation of o for all g rades
    oHelper = LpVariable.matrix("oH", (gModel), 0, None, LpInteger)
    #Njg_Helper = Total students in a particular school
    Njg_helper = LpVariable.matrix("NH", (sModel), 0, None, LpInteger)






    formulation = LpProblem("School Consolidation Model", LpMinimize)

    formulation += lpSum(((prob.Njg[i][g] * x[i][g][j] for j in sModel) for g in gModel) for i in sModel)

    for i in sModel:
        for j in sModel:
            for g in gModel:
                formulation += x[i][g][j] * prob.D[i][j] <= prob.d1

    for i in sModel:
        for j in sModel:
            for g in gModel:
                formulation += x[i][g][j] <= y[j]
    for i in sModel:
        for g in gModel:
            formulation += lpSum(x[i][g][j] for j in sModel) <= 1 - y[i]

    for j in sModel:
        formulation += ((lpSum(prob.Njg[j][g] for g in gModel) - prob.Nmax) * (1 - y[j])) <= 0

    for i in sModel:
        for j in sModel:
            if i != j and Beta[i] * Beta[j] != 1:
                formulation += (prob.D[i][j] - prob.d2) >= (y[i] + y[j] - 2) * M

    for g in gModel:
        formulation += lpSum(o[j][g] for j in sModel) == oHelper[g]
        formulation += lpSum(prob.Njg[i][g] for i in sModel) == oHelper[g]
        for j1 in sModel:
            formulation += lpSum(prob.Njg[i1][g]*x[i1][g][j1] for i1 in sModel) == o[j1][g]-prob.Njg[j1][g]*y[j1]

    formulation.solve()
```

Comment: You're likely to get more useful input if you copy the code you're finding errors in into the question itself, rather than linking to a zip file - hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, done.
Can you guide to get some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have bugs in the model. I would try the following:

- Build a minimum model with all the features. That is, build first the smallest model you can build (a toy example) so the generated model can be human readable. With one or two students, only two locations, etc. A model you can compute the solution by hand.
- Using `Pulp` function, create an LP file containing the model.
- Run the model with other solver to check that you get the same *not feasible* results (for instance, try SCIP if you are in a none commercial project).
- Read the lp file to check/find the bug in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the help and consideration.
We have finally be able to find the solution

Answer (score -1):

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class WelcomeScreen(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=u"Stock Cutting", pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                          size=wx.Size(448, 395), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

        # prevent resizing of the window
        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.Size(448, 394), wx.Size(448, 395))

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #create image object using the jpg file stored in the root directory
        self.m_bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap(u"test.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY),
                                         wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)

        bSizer1.Add(self.m_bitmap1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"START", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.m_button1.SetFont(wx.Font(15, 71, 90, 92, False, wx.EmptyString))
        self.m_button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.next, self.m_button1)
        bSizer1.Add(self.m_button1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
                               "Do you really want to close this application?",
                               "Confirm Exit", wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

    # function to go to the next screen to enter the data
    def next(self, event):
        self.Show(False)
#        start = home.HomeScreen(None, prob)

# main method to start the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    WelcomeScreen = WelcomeScreen(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```